# How to replace a specific part of the regular expression(regex) by white space?

Tags: .net, regex

In my aspx files (using Visual basic 2013) I opened the Find and Replace tab:
[image]

Now what I want is to replace all ShowInCustomization="false" that are on the same line with Visible="false" in a  tag with white space.
i.e:

Change:

`<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="100" FieldName="RM_Name" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="0">`

To:

`<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="100" FieldName="RM_Name" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" VisibleIndex="0">`

And using the regex: `<dx:GridView.*Visible="false".*(?<showIn>ShowInCustomizationForm="True")` I was able to find all those lines, so now what is the regex to use that will accomplish my task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove a part of string matched with your regex, and you used a named capturing group to enclose the part of pattern that will match the substring you need to remove. It is a wrong idea because we usually capture what we need to *keep* and just match what we need to remove.

Another issue you may encounter is that the `Visible="false"` comes before the attribute you need to remove, and doing it with a single expression requires a lookahead.

Besides, you must consider matching and checking only within a single tag. `.*` will match across tags as it matches any char but a newline char.

You may consider

**Find what**: `(<dx:GridView(?=[^<]*?\sVisible="false")[^<]*?)\s+ShowInCustomizationForm="True"`
**Replace with**: `$1`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3cdx%3aGridView%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3c%5d*%3f%5csVisible%3d%22false%22%29%5b%5e%3c%5d*%3f%29%5cs%2bShowInCustomizationForm%3d%22True%22&i=%3cdx%3aGridViewDataTextColumn+Width%3d%22100%22+FieldName%3d%22RM_Name%22+ReadOnly%3d%22True%22+Visible%3d%22false%22+ShowInCustomizationForm%3d%22True%22+VisibleIndex%3d%220%22%3e%0d%0a%3cdx%3aGridViewDataTextColumn+Width%3d%22100%22+FieldName%3d%22RM_Name%22+ReadOnly%3d%22True%22+ShowInCustomizationForm%3d%22True%22+Visible%3d%22false%22+VisibleIndex%3d%220%22%3e&r=%241)

**Details**

- `(<dx:GridView(?=[^<]*?\sVisible="false")[^<]*?)` - Capturing group 1 (what we'll keep by replacing with the `$1` placeholder, we use this as an anchor, left-hand context):

  - `<dx:GridView` - a literal string
  - `(?=[^<]*?\sVisible="false")` - a positive lookahead that checks the presence of 0 or more chars other than `<` as few as possible (`[^<]*?`), a whitespace (`\s`) and then a `Visible="false"` substring immediately to the right of the current location
  - `[^<]*?` - 0 or more chars other than `<` as few as possible
- `\s+ShowInCustomizationForm="True"` - 1+ whitespaces and a literal `ShowInCustomizationForm="True"` substring.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly but I have another question please, what if now I want to do the same task but the ```ShowInCustomizationForm="True"``` is place before the ```Visible="false"``` ? i.e: ```<dx:GridView.*ShowInCustomizationForm="True".*Visible="false"```

Comment: @DanielK `(<dx:GridView(?=[^<]*?\sVisible="false")[^<]*?)\s+ShowInCustomizationForm="True"`